# Clarification regarding Eq. (2.6.21) Weinberg Vol. 1

Tags: rotation, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

While reading the action of time reversal operator for massless particles, I was going through the derivation for Eq. (2.6.21) from Weinberg Vol. 1 which proceeds as follows

$$
\begin{aligned}
U^{-1}(R(-\hat p))U(R(\hat p)R_{2})
&=\mathrm e^{-i(\pi - \theta)J_{2}}\mathrm e^{ -i(\phi \pm \pi)J_{3}}\mathrm e^{i\phi J_{3}}\mathrm e^{i\theta J_{2}}\mathrm e^{-i\pi J_{2}}      \hspace{35pt}(1)\\
&= \mathrm e^{-i(\pi - \theta)J_{2}}\mathrm e^{\mp i J_{3}}\mathrm e^{-i(\pi - \theta)J_{2}} \hspace{71pt}(2)\\
&= \mathrm e^{\pm i J_{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then he makes a statement that rotation of $\pm 180^\circ$ about the $z$ axis reverses the sign of $J_{2}$, but why? And even if this is true, why does the sign of $J_{3}$ change in the very next step ?

Comment: A rotation of $\pm 180^\circ$ about any axis changes the sign of any vector orthogonal to that axis (and $\boldsymbol J$ is a vector).

Comment: ok. That is fine but why does $J_{3}$ change sign ?

Comment: whithout further details, I cannot tell (for example, I don't have a copy of W. around right now, and there is a mistake in the last line of yours: $\exp(-i(\pi-\theta)$ makes no sense)

Comment: Yeah. I just checked and have made necessary corrections.

Comment: I have edited your question: I hope you dont mind (you can revert the edit if you want, by clicking on the `edit` button). Now: do you know how to get (2) from (1)? and (3) from (2)? finally, what is "the very next step"?

Comment: Upto step (3) is clear to me. In the very next step I think I need to move $J_{3}$ across $J_{2}$ and since $J_{2}$ picks up a minus sign it cancels with the term on the left

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I have made some changes and provided the very next step in the calculation as given in the book.